# Bulk INSERT not inserting data

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, bulk

When running the code below management studio shows an error in which it is set down.

I need to insert simple text data into the tables through BULK INSERT. The code for insertion is as follows:

```
BULK INSERT Pais FROM 'C:\[bulkdata]\shared\01-Pais.txt' 
WITH(MAXERRORS = 0, CODEPAGE = 'ACP', FIELDTERMINATOR = 'ø', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', KEEPNULLS,
ERRORFILE = 'C:\[bulkdata]\shared\teste.txt')
```

The file I'm using to test this command has only one line for inserting data,
**teste.txt:**

```
BrasilØ01058
```

The error returned is as follows:

```
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

teste.txt:

```
BrasilØ01058BrasilØ01058
```

It seems to me that this is trying to insert the value twice on the same line, but as the setting shows, it usually inserts into other projects. Can my user be without permission? I have already created a specific user with all permissions and also set the server the permission to perform bulk operations.

teste.txt.Error.Txt:

```
Row 1 File Offset 0 ErrorFile Offset 0 - HRESULT 0x80004005
```

[image]

Comment: The first thing I would do is to check that the format of the file is exactly like the real file in something like notepad++ that shows the hidden characters.. Sounds like it it looking for a line feed or carriage return or both at the end of the line that it is not getting.

Comment: I just made a simple test and it seems that you are using javascript.... `var t1 = 'ø'; var t2 = 'Ø'; console.log(t1 === t2);` and the result is `false`

Comment: What I mean is that your field terminator in your file and the one specified in your bulk statement, are not the same

Comment: @HLGEM I already did this test, I did not find anything out of the ordinary. What is strange is the error generated, as if you tried to insert the first line twice.

Comment: The character that defines the column separator must be different from the Row separator, so they are different. @Hackerman

Comment: No, what I mean is that your `FIELDTERMINATOR` character is different from the one that you use in your file(teste.txt)...they look the same but they are not the same character `ø and Ø`

Comment: @Hackerman I just tested with the two and generated the same error

Comment: @Hackerman I just tested with another character in place and it worked, I changed by comma. But this character should work, I have used the same in other projects and always worked normally, there must be some configuration of SQL Server that unprotected against the use of this character. For my data are of various types, and to remind me, the only thing that does not repeat itself would be this character.

Comment: Ok, try this way: `BrasilØ01058` and in your bulk statement `FIELDTERMINATOR = 'Ø'`(copy and paste)

Comment: @Hackerman same error. § this caracter works, I will use it, you can enter as your answer although it is not the other character that is working you gave the tip.

Comment: Issue with the database collation maybe?

Comment: @JacobH Maybe so, but I did not change anything. In short, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a `character` issue, you can try with another one like `§`.
You just need to do a little tweak:

```
FIELDTERMINATOR = '§'
```

And your `01-Pais.txt` file:

```
Brasil§01058
```

> **Update:** It seems that also a mix of database collation and file encoding issue, could have messing up the `bulk` operation. Saving the file as `ANSI`, instead of `UTF-8` seems to have corrected the original issue. It seems that also using `CODEPAGE=1252` or `DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'` should have fixed the issue.

Comment: 'Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (Id).
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".'

Comment: To insert through the system via C# now this error has occurred. I'm using the entity framework to generate Seed.

Comment: I found the real problem with all this. The files that contain the data (my bulkdata.txt for example) should be saved as ANSI and not UTF-8 it was in, just open it in notepad and save in this format that solved the problem using the first character I was trying to . Add this to your response to other people.